# Script to calculate memory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

trying to solve my script with simple explanation of the process as i am new to linux i could be doing something wrong

Creating a memory.sh script which will calculate Firefox's memory usage (as a % of total memory)

**1. List the processes with their memory usage (in percentage)**

```
ps -e -o pmem,args |
```

**2. Search this list for lines that contain the word firefox**

```
ps -e -o pmem,args | grep -i firefox
```

**3. Use only the column that displays memory usage**

```
ps -e -o pmem,args | grep -i firefox | grep -v grep
```

**4. Display each item in the list by adding a +**

**5. Add a 0 at the end of the list**

**6. Add quit on a new line**

**7. Do the calculation**

Comment: Is presenting this a a script a requirement ? You can very easily get to the total percentage based memory usage with a simpler Awk one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

On GNU/Linux and with `zsh`:

```
printf 'Total: %.3g%%\n' ${(j[+])${(f)"$(
  pgrep -f firefox | LC_ALL=C xargs -r ps -o pmem=
)"}}
```

Where:

- `pgrep -f firefox` reports the pids of processes whose arg list contains `firefox`
- `xargs -r` passes those if any as arguments to `ps`
- `ps -o pmem=` outputs the memory usage percentage (in English format with `.` as decimal radix character with `LC_ALL=C` for future-proofing).
- `"$(...)"` captures `ps` output, with IFS-splitting disabled thanks to quoting.
- `${(f)...}` splits it on linefeeds instead.
- `${(j[+])...}` joins the resulting words with `+`
- `$(( ... ))` the result is interpreted as an arithmetic expression
- `printf 'Total: %.3g%%\n'` and printed with default 3 digit precision.

Now note that `pmem` is expressed with just one digit after `.`. So for processes using little memory individually, that will give you very poor precision. For instance, a process using 100KiB or 2MiB on a system with 4GiB will equally be seen as using 0.0% memory, 200 of those using 2MiB would use up 400MiB, so 10%, but the computed sum above would give you 0.

To get better precision, you should rather compute the cumulative `rss` of all your processes and do the calculation by `hand`:

```
pattern=firefox
used=$((
  ${(j[+])${(f)"$(
    pgrep -f -- "$pattern" | LC_ALL=C xargs -r ps -o rss=
  )"}}
))
grep '^MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo | read x total x
printf 'Total: %.3g%%\n' 'used * 100. / total'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which adheres more or less to your formatting instructions (without any output format example, it's hard to *guess* what you expect exactly):

```
$ \ps -eo pmem,args | awk '/[Ff]irefox/ {totmem+=$1;printf "%s+", $1} 
                           END{printf "%s%2.1f%s\n", "0=",totmem,"%"}'
4.0+0.3+0.8+1.1+1.2+1.0+1.0+0.5+0.5+0.5+0=10.9%     # example output w/o the one liner's own memory consumption
```

But you can also produce the total directly:

```
$ \ps -eo pmem,args | awk '/[Ff]irefox/ {totmem+=$1}
                           END{print "total memory used:",totmem,"%"}'
total memory used: 10.9 %         # example output
```

*(tested with GNU Awk 5.1.1)*

Comment: @Cbhihe the "tradtional" method is to use a regex that won't & can't match itself - e.g. `/[f]irefox/` will match "firefox" but not "[f]irefox".  You seem to have that in your second example, but still have the `!/totmem/` which isn't necessary.

Comment: @cas: got it now and corrected. Tx